# icon error in Android actcionbar xml

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I am beginning android development and I am having problems making an action bar. Basically I am following some code form online and I am getting an error saying I do not have an icon:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_search').
```

I did some research and thought my problem was I did not have all the extras downloaded from the android SDK. But after downloading all the extras it didnt work. I know I could just find the icon and download it, but I do not want to have to download all the icons individually, therefore I think I am missing something. My xml file I am getting the error with looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:title="@string/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />


</menu>
```

this is under menu>main.xml

Comment: do you have that bitmap or are you trying to using the android one? @android:drawable/ic_menu_search

Comment: I am just using eclipse and thought all these icons would have been included in the android development environment.

Comment: Nope. did you tried with @android:drawable/ic_menu_search  ?

Comment: @blackbelt that fixed it thank you! Now whats the difference, I would like to understand why what I tried didnt work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the android icon, you should add the `android` prefix after `@`. Change

```
@drawable/ic_menu_search
```

in

```
@android:drawable/ic_menu_search
```

`@drawable` looks inside the `res/drawable*` folder of your app. If you want to access to the android resources. strings/drawable/id you have to put the `android` prefix after the `@`. with that prefix you will access to the android.R class not to your.R class